# pyfluidsynth import error

Tags: python, jack

on OSX 10.7.5, i ran `port install fluidsynth` and `pip install pyfluidsynth` successfully, and fluidsynth works from the terminal.

but `from fluidsynth.fluidsynth import *` outputs

```
OSError: dlopen(libfluidsynth.so.1, 6): image not found
```

any ideas?

Comment: try `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib python -m fluidsynth.fluidsynth`. what happens?

Comment: same thing. my /opt/local/lib has `libfluidsynth.1.dylib`, `libfluidsynth.dylib`, and `libfluidsynth.la`, but no `libfluidsynth.so.1`.  
  
is that it? what does the `.so` mean?

Comment: Try `cd /opt/local/lib; sudo ln -s libfluidsynth.dylib libfluidsynth.so.1`. `.so` is the library suffix used primarily on Linux.